# JavaFX 3D performance - initial rendering very slow

Tags: 3d, javafx

I have written a Java FX application which reads a binary STL file, loads the data into a JavaFX mesh and then displays it as a 3D render. Most of the code is taken from the molecule viewer example in the Oracle JavaFX tutorial. I made a new subclass of TriangleMesh called STLMesh which scans in the STL facets and sets the points and faces arrays accordingly.

The code works well for small examples: an STL file with 1000 triangles appears instantly. However, a file with just under 14,000 triangles takes 50 seconds to first appear, and I have other larger examples that do not appear within a resonable time. Once on the screen, I can spin and pan the display very smoothly. My question: *how do I avoid this long delay in initial rendering?*

The code that sets up the JavaFX scene graph is below - it is basically the top level code from moelcule viewer, but using an instance of my STLMesh class instead of the molecules.

The delay happens within the JavaFX thread after the stage.show() is executed. Other JavaFX windows are non-responsive during the delay. Judging by the disk light, there is no significant swapping activity during the delay: it appears to be compute bound.

I am running on a Toshiba Tecra laptop - I do not know much about the graphics hardware on these machines.

I have tried the Jim modelimporter from http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html which I believe is implemented in JavaFX: it renders all of my STL files within a second or two. They do not provide source, so I do not know what, if any, cleverness they are using to avoid the problem that I am experiencing.

```
STLviewer(File file) {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    buildScene();
    buildCamera();
    buildAxes();

    PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial(Color.YELLOW);

    final Group sGroup = new Group();

    MeshView meshView = new MeshView(new STLMesh(file));
    meshView.setMaterial(material);
    // meshView.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
    meshView.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
    sGroup.getChildren().add(meshView);
    world.getChildren().addAll(sGroup);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 600, true);
    scene.setFill(Color.GREY);
    handleMouse(scene, world);

    scene.setCamera(camera);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Can you supply a link to a model (and model loading code) for which this is an issue for you so that somebody could attempt to replicate the issue?  See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've stripped the STLviewer out of its application, zipped up the code and a couple of STL files and put it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30126557/simpleSTLViewer.zip. Unzip the contents, recompile if you wish (I have put .class files in there as well) and run as **java SimpleSTLviewer**. Two STL files are rendered: a small one and a model of a milk churn. On my machine, the second render takes almost a minute. Once rendered, performance is excellent.

Answer (score 3):

The length of the face-array in STLMesh.java is too long:

old : int faces[] = new int[facetCount * 18];

new : int faces[] = new int[facetCount * 6]; (3 coord + 3 texCoord indices per triangle/face)

It seems that the internal setup of the TriangelMesh 'goes mad' due to so many triangles referring to the same vertex (index = zero) for all three corners.

Additionally, the array for texCoords should be chosen shorter. Even if no texture is applied, TriangleMesh requires texCoords. A single one is sufficient in this case:

new : float texCoords[] = {0f, 0f};

Comment: This has fixed my problem. I am extremely grateful to InteractiveMesh. Stackoverflow is a wonderful resource.